# www site shows blank screen (read http header in Firebug?)

Tags: .htaccess, dns, subdomain, firebug

My domain http://bretthowardsproul.com is active but the www version, www.bretthowardsproul.com , shows a blank screen.

I added this .htaccess but it doesn't change the results:

```
# Redirect www to no-www - via bit.ly/www-no-www
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^bretthowardsproul.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://bretthowardsproul.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I then tried test.bretthowardsproul.com and got a 404. So is it something in my .htaccess?

If not, do I need to do something with a CNAME? Is there something I can check in Firebug to see what's going on at www ?

Comment: I see something. I'm using Chrome... Maybe it took a little while to update the DNS settings?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in any browser. It's been at least 24-36 hours..

Comment: From the website: `We are working on a relaunch of this website and plan to have it finished by the end of March 2011. Here’s a sneak peek:` Does that seem right?

Comment: wow, yes, that's right. so maybe it's cache issue on my end? in all those browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the "www" CNAME exists for your domain, and is pointing to your @ record, otherwise "www" traffic won't go to the same place that your domain goes to without "www".

A quick google search should help you figure out how to add the CNAME to your registrar.  For GoDaddy, this is helpful: http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=47610

Comment: ok I'll check. Out of curiosity, shouldn't the htaccess work regardless of what the CNAME is? Shouldn't it work for test.domain.com too?

Comment: Not necessarily, because a DNS lookup for "asdf.example.com" doesn't default to "example.com" if the "asdf" CNAME doesn't exist.  Your htaccess files exist at "example.com", but the request won't make it there unless DNS points to your server.